# AngularJS: Show if X > Y and add class

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am building my first app. It is an ordering system where a customer can add items to the cart. Everything is working well. However, my client would like a way to alert the customer if they try to add a quantity to the cart that is greater than the current stock.

My client doesn't want to show stock levels, unless the customer adds something greater than the stock available.

I have a table with stock items in each row. I'd like to do three things, if the stock level is greater that available stock, I'd like to change:
• Class on the table row
• Add class disabled to the submit
• Show a div that has the available stock in.

To make matters a little more interesting, customers have to order by packs and not individual items.

Basically, I am trying to get the following code to work:

This is the general markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="series_detail in productDetail | filter:filter">
   <td>{{series_detail.sku}}</td>
   <td>{{series_detail.size}}</td>
   <td>{{series_detail.price</td>
   <td>{{series_detail.pack}}</td>
   <td ng-model="totalitems" ng-init="0">{{qty * series_detail.pack | number}}</td>
   <td><span class="itemtotal">{{series_detail.price * qty | number:2}}</span></td>                           

   <td class="form-inline" style="text-align:right;">
       <input type="submit" class="add_to_cart_submit btn btn-danger btn-small" value="Add">
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to then show this div

```
<div ng-show="'{{totalitems}}' > '{{series_detail.stock}}'">Yo, no stock dude</div>
```

I have tried adding a model, 'totalitems' to a row and then using ngShow to pop it up. However, it seems that 'totalitems' is evaluating to nothing. I've experimented with a few other options, but nothing has worked (ngIF etc.).

Regarding the changing of class, I am guessing, that once I get this sorted, I can transfer the expression to ngClass? I have played with this, and again, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: It would help to have the `controller` code (where `totalitems` and `productDetail` are defined) with the template.

Comment: I suggest you make a demo in plunker. We have to assume you have an `in stock` field in data to compare to and hard to help without seeing basic controller code. Also hard to know what you mean by `package`. Like coke comes in singles or 12 packs? can only have a 12 pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided this line goes inside the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-show="qty * series_detail.pack > series_detail.stock">Yo, no stock dude</div>
```

For the class indication, lets say on tr, you could use the same expression as:

```
<tr ng-class="{outOfStock: (qty * series_detail.pack > series_detail.stock)}" ng-repeat="series_detail in productDetail | filter:filter">
```

`outOfStock` is class in your CSS.

BTW,

```
<td ng-model="totalitems" ng-init="0">{{qty * series_detail.pack | number}}</td>
```

does not set `totalitems` to whatever `{{qty * series_detail.pack | number}}` evaluates to.

If you really need `totalItems` in your model a possible option is to have a method on the `series_detail` instance

```
objRef.totalItems = function(qty) {
    return qty * this.pack;
}
```

and use it as:

```
<div ng-show="series_detail.totalItems(qty) > series_detail.stock">Yo, no stock dude</div>

<td>{{series_detail.totalItems(qty) | number}}</td>
```

Comment: You sir, are a freakin' legend. Thanks. Works like a charm!! I love this community! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not to sure to understand everything but something like this should works ?

```
<div ng-show="isStockAddedGreaterThanAvailable()">{{series_detail.stock}} Yo, no stock dude </div>
```

And in your controller

```
 $scope.isStockAddedGreaterThanAvailable = function(){
   ....
}
```